# ¿Cómo puedo escribir esta búsqueda con MATCH (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo dos columnas de la hoja HOJA:

> Columna A -> Codigo1
>
> Columna B -> Codigo2

Quiero encontrar la fila que contiene `Codigo1` y `Codigo2`. Hago algo como esto, pero no funciona, falta algo y no logro que funcione:

```
Fila = Application.Match(Codigo1 & "&" & Codigo2,
Application.Union(Worksheets("Hoja").Range("A:A"), Worksheets("Hoja").Range("B:B"),0)
```

La parte del rango me parece que esta mal, trato de indicarle que busque en las columnas A y B, los códigos `CODIGO1` y `CODIGO2` (Se entiende que `CODIGO1` está en la columna A y `CODIGO2` en la columna B)

¿Saben cómo hago que funcione?

Comment: En la própia documentacion de [Match](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match), tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo con una macro.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Tendrás que llevarte todo el rango a una matriz (Array), y hacer un bucle dentro de la matriz mirando ambas columnas hasta que encuentres el valor. En Excel, lo que tú quieres hacer se haría en forma matricial, pero tú no quieres poner la fórmula en una celda, sino que lo calcule VBA, así que mejor llévate todos los datos a un array y lo recorres.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería servirte:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim C As Range, LastRow As Long, Variable1 As String, Variable2 As String

    Variable1 = "CODIGO1"
    Variable2 = "CODIGO2"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja") 'pon el nombre de la hoja que contiene los datos
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each C In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            If C = Variable1 And C.Offset(0, 1) = Variable2 Then
                MsgBox "Los datos están en la fila " & C.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next C
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer usando la función [BUSCARV](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/buscarv-funci%C3%B3n-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

```
=BUSCARV($A1;B:B;1;FALSO)
```

Y luego pues lo arrastras a todas las demás celdas.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver lo que pide James con tu respuesta. Imagina que tienes diez filas con 2 columnas de datos (20 celdas). En la primera columna, en alguna fila está el valor `Código1` y en la misma fila pero en la segunda columna está el valor `Código2`. Quiere saber en qué posición sucede eso.Tu fórmiula simplemente devuelve un valor, no una posición.